# JMS | IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5 | How to see messages and their formats lying on queues

Tags: soap, queue, jms, websphere

I am working on a POC wherein I am trying to achieve SOAP over JMS. Basically I'll be submitting my SOAP messages directly to the jms queue and a consumer will further read these SOAP messages and process them. The reason we want to stick to SOAP is because it is a standard formatand we'll not have to do something extra to design a new standard form messages.

For this poc I am using the default messaging provider which comes by default with IBM websphere app server 8.5. I referred to the [following](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0402_du/0402_du.html) and I am able to submit my messages to queue. The problem is that I expected the SOAP to stay as XML/String on my queue however it is getting converted into a byte message.

I want to check the message and its type on my queue using some kind of queue browser tool which could work with IBM WAS8.5 . I googled and found that there are a lot of Queue browser tools available for servers like Glassfish etc but I couldn't find any tool or option for IBM WAS8.5?

Can you please guide me on what I can do to ensure that my SOAP message stays as XML on JMS queue and any GUI tool/option I could use to see the message and its type on Queue ?

Regards
Aakash

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SIB Explorer tool to view the messages on the queue in WAS. The link to the tool is [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=fe21f954-66dd-40c2-bfc4-45eb0b7d51eb). 

There is also the SIB Destination Handler tool that allows you to perform more actions on the messages that you might find useful for your issue (like printing out properties etc). The SIB Destination Handler tool can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021439).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tools mentioned by [whitfiea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26056302/3701228) you can use web admin console and go to:

```
Buses > myBus > Destinations > myQueue > Queue points >  
myQueue@rad9vmNode02.server1-myBus > (switch to the Runtime tab) > Messages
```

then select the message. You should be able to see the message contents.